# use multiple form instances jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, primefaces

my jsf appication is designed so that by clicking on a menuitem the corresponding page is displayed in a newly created tab. the pages displayed on tabs have their own form element & backing bean. 
normally this works pretty well, but could not find a way how to solve the situation when multiple instances of the same form is used concurrently, eg. more 'add new employee' tabs are opened at the same time. 
i try to use a `@SessionScoped` managed bean with a `Map` containing instances of the form data (currently only one string for simplicity) like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="employeeBean")
@SessionScoped
public class EmployeeBean extends BaseManagedBean implements Serializable{

    private Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private String formId;

    public void newForm(){
        this.formId=RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10);
        logger.debug("newForm: formId: " + formId);
        this.fields.put(formId, new String());
}
//... etc
}
```

when i click on a menuitem, a new random `formId` is generated and new form data holder is added to the `fields` map.

the jsf page is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<div class="dataContainer clearfix">
<h:form id = "#{employeeBean.formId}">
    <h:inputText id="empField1" value="#{employeeBean.fields[employeeBean.formId]}" />
    <p:commandLink action="#{employeeBean.action}" value="Action" id="actionLink">
    </p:commandLink>
</h:form>
</div>  
</html>
```

the last opened tab instance works perfectly but the old ones do not. if the `commandLink` is pressed on older tabs the right form is submitted and the `getFormId` method is called once in the restore view phase, but nothing else is called in my `EmployeeBean`.
if i use fixed formId not the random `#{employeebean.formId}` then always the first opened tab's data is submitted. (multiple forms with same id on the page).

i suppose something is wrong with my component tree.
i am using `Primefaces`'s `TabView` component (based on jquery) and i add new tabs to the tab component in a jquery javascript function.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? or suggest a better way to solve problem? what is the right approach to handle situtations like this?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: probably not the best solution but i managed to submit all of my tabs. the trick is that i use the same id for all forms and i replaced the `PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest` with my own AjaxRequest which always posts the current form (where the `CommandLink` is pressed) instead of the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need here a session scoped bean? E.g. do you want to reach bean-content from other pages? If not, than maybe you could simply make your `EmployeeBean` request scoped. Than you don't need a map inside your `employeeBean`, and you `valuebindings` could also be more simple...